# Differential Expression Using MetaboDiff

Tags: r, bioinformatics

My data is contained in mydata.csv file.

```
Sample   Metabolite1   Metabolite2   Metabolite3   Group
control1  1.2           0.8           1.5           A
control2  0.9           1.1           1.2           A
control3  1.5           1.2           1.8           A
s_treat1  0.7           0.9           1.3           B
s_treat2  1.1           1.3           0.9           B
s_treat3  1.0           0.7           1.4           B

> library(MetaboDiff)
> 
> data <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header = TRUE)
> 
> sample_names <- data[1, 2:ncol(data)]
> 
> metadata_cols <- grep("^N_", colnames(data), value = TRUE)
> 
> for (col in metadata_cols) {
>    attributes(data[[col]]) <- NULL
> }
> 
> cols <- c(2:(ncol(data) - 1), ncol(data))
> 
> met <- diff_test(data[, cols], group_factors = "Group")

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘metadata<-’ for signature ‘"data.frame"
```

I'd like to find FC, log2FC, p.ajusted and -LOG10(p)

I got the Error. How should I deal with this problem?

p.s. My data was obtained from LC-MS/MS technique, and the values are intensity.

Comment: I think you should read this: https://rawgit.com/andreasmock/MetaboDiff/master/vignettes/MetaboDiff_tutorial.html. The package operates on `MultiAssayExperiment` objects which are created from two dataframes and a matrix containing sample info